# Given an (a * b) list, return a (a * b list) list

Tags: list, f#

A funky title perhaps, but I'm having a problem with the following:

Given a list of type `(a * b) list`, I want to create a new list with type `(a * b list) list`. An example:

Given list `let testList = [(1,"c");(2,"a");(1,"b")]`, my function should return `[(1, ["c";"b"]; (2, ["a"])]`.

I have the following, but I'm a little stuck on how to continue:

```
let rec toRel xs =
    match xs with
    | (a,b)::rest -> (a,[b])::toRel rest
    | _           -> []
```

Comment: You can use ``List.groupBy``

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the built-in function `List.groupBy` and then map to remove the redundant key:

```
testList |> List.groupBy fst |> List.map (fun (k,v) -> (k, List.map snd v))

// val it : (int * string list) list = [(1, ["c"; "b"]); (2, ["a"])]
```

Otherwise if you want to continue with a match you can do something like this:

```
let toRel x = 
    let rec loop acc xs =
        match xs with
        | (k, b) :: rest ->
            let acc =
                match Map.tryFind k acc with
                | Some v -> Map.add k (b::v) acc
                | None   -> Map.add k [b] acc
            loop acc rest
        | _             -> acc
    loop Map.empty x |> Map.toList
```

Or using `Option.toList` you can write it:

```
let toRel x = 
    let rec loop acc xs =
        match xs with
        | (k, b) :: rest ->
            let acc =
                let lst = Map.tryFind k acc |> Option.toList |> List.concat
                Map.add k (b::lst) acc
            loop acc rest
        | _              -> acc
    loop Map.empty x |> Map.toList
```

Comment: That is a very elegant solution. Do you have a suggestion for doing it without higher-order functions?

Comment: I just added an example with a match which I think is what you were trying to do. But you can also use iterators.